# Google app engine blobstore file upload exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am having exception in google app engine file upload . I used below code from accompanied url,

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/blobstore/

and the code ,

```
<body>
    <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

and the exception is :

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call blobstore.CreateUploadURL in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException.foreignThread(ApiProxy.java:792)
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:112)
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:65)
    com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.createUploadUrl(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:70)
    com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.createUploadUrl(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:44)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you figured something out?